# scipy.stats.spearmanr: Warning: divide by zero encountered in divide

Tags: python, scipy

I use `scipy.stats.spearmanr(a,b)` and I get:

```
Warning: divide by zero encountered in divide
```

The operation ends correctly, but the warning is displayed. Both `a` and `b` are "normal" data, (no "zero-only" vectors etc.). Any idea what is the cause, or how to suspend the warning?

EDIT:

This is the offending line in `spearmanr`:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.pyc in spearmanr(a, b, axis)
   2226     rs = np.corrcoef(ar,br,rowvar=axisout)
   2227 
-> 2228     t = rs * np.sqrt((n-2) / ((rs+1.0)*(1.0-rs)))
   2229     prob = distributions.t.sf(np.abs(t),n-2)*2
   2230
```

Comment: If you can post values for `a` and `b` which reproduce the problem, that would be helpful. Also, setting `np.seterr(all='raise')` will turn the warning into an exception, which will tell you on which line inside `spearmanr` the division by zero is occuring.

Comment: division by zero is by design, rs=1 on diagonal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

division by zero is by design, rs=1 on diagonal. This happens for any values.

However, in scipy 0.9 this error has been silenced locally within the spearmanr function. 
The corresponding sourceline contains

`np.seterr(divide='ignore')  # rs can have elements equal to 1`

Comment: Strange, thou, that I have rather updated packages (@ubuntu) and still I had to silence it manually